[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ... is not supported
Project setup

Electron app using electron-builder, which uses vite as build system. The build system is still almost identical to the template.
TypeScript, with the .ts file extension
ESM and import everywhere in our code. We do not use require() anywhere in our code base.
Obviously, we're using various third-party npm libraries.

Reproduction

npm create @quick-start/electron@latest


Project name: electron-app
Select a framework: › svelte
Add TypeScript? Yes
Add Electron updater plugin? Yes
Enable Electron download mirror proxy? No


cd electron-app; yarn install; yarn run dev -- works
yarn add electron-context-menu, and import it to main.ts, as shown below.
Start the app using yarn run dev

Note: This is an ESM-only (!) third-party npm library, not built by me. The problem is not limited to this library. I have seen the same error multiple times in the past, with different libraries. It appears to be a generic problem with vite in combination with ESM-only modules.
Actual result

Error, see below for console output

Expected result
(and actual result before adding electron-context-menu)

App starts without errors

Code
Reduced code of the e2/src/main/index.ts file:
import { BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import contextMenu from 'electron-context-menu'; // <-- fails here

function createWindow(): void {
  contextMenu({});
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({...})
  ...
}

createWindow();
...

You find the rest of the files, including the build config files, at https://github.com/mustang-im/mustang/tree/4fc959d/e2
Error
App threw an error during load
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /e2/node_modules/electron-context-menu/index.js from /e2/out/main/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of /e2/node_modules/electron-context-menu/index.js in /e2/out/main/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/e2/out/main/index.js:37:21)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)
    at loadApplicationPackage (/e2/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/main.js:121:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/e2/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/main.js:233:9)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)
    at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:123937
    at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:124140
    at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:124144
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /e2/node_modules/electron-context-menu/index.js from /e2/out/main/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of /e2/node_modules/electron-context-menu/index.js in /e2/out/main/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/e2/out/main/index.js:37:21)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)
    at loadApplicationPackage (/e2/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/main.js:121:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/e2/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/main.js:233:9)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)
    at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:123937
    at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:124140
    at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:124144
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)

Fix attempts
What I tried to fix it:

Error msg suggests to "change the require of ...": We're not using require() at all. Very confusing and misleading error msg. I suspect vite converts the import into a require()?
I've tried with and without type: module in e2/package.json (of the electron app) - same result. Does not fix it.
Various SO answers are not applicable (already tried, see above) or suggest HACKs that don't address the underlying problem (see below)

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported
Error: require() of ES modules is not supported when importing node-fetch
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module index.js not supported



Rejected solutions
What I consider a bad fix with other disadvantages and what I do not want to do:

Use a dynamic import(), because completely unnecessary here.
Rename our code files and change the file extensions
Downgrade the third-party library and use an old, unmaintained version of it.

Possible solutions
What I could imagine might work:

Change the build configuration of vite to emit import/ESM code instead of transpiling into require() code.
Fix vite?


Do you transpile your code to CommonJS? Can you create a [mcve] and add the transpiled code?

As described, this is the default electron-builder setup. I didn't build it, so I cannot really minimize it. You can see the complete and exact code in the link that is part of the question.

The default electron-builder setup works. Your setup doesn't work. The code is probably not the problem. It's probably the configuration. You haven't posted any configuration. Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific questions and specific answers. Your question is not answerable. Users would have to guess what the problem could be.

As said, I've posted the configuration in the question: See https://github.com/mustang-im/mustang/tree/4fc959d/e2

Questions on Stack Overflow have to be self-contained. The goal of Stack Overflow is to help future users with similar questions. It's not a discussion board or help forum to help one single user. It's more like a wiki. External resource can change and links can break. Your questions becomes useless for future users. Please provide a [mcve] in your question, not as external resource.

As mentioned, this is a default setup. I've been able to reproduce the issue with a minimal testcase application. I've now added the detailed steps more explicitly to the reproduction. The problem is reproducible without my app, only with the reproduction steps given. I didn't modify the code at all, other than what is listed in the 5 steps. The problem is also reproducible with other libraries, not just the mentioned one. It's a generic problem, affecting everybody who uses this generic template setup and ESM-only libs.

In that case, I would say, it's a bug. I would open an issue at https://github.com/alex8088/quick-start/issues The repository isn't really active. I wouldn't call it deprecated, but most files in the projcet are 2 years old or older. The documentation mentions npm v7 or older.

Is there a reason you use this template and not the official steps? I can't even build the project. I get ERROR  An entry point is required in the electron vite main config, which can be specified using "build.lib.entry" or "build.rollupOptions.input".

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
